# solr doesn't search in all fields

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I have indexed my table and able to search in q parameter like

```
q=field:*

q=field:parameter

q=*:* ( displays all results )
```

But When I give query like this

```
q=*:parameter
```

I get

```
undefined field *
```

How do I search in all fields and use the same query ( i.e q=*:parma ) and make it work ?

here's my schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="enrol_no" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="addr" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="phno" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="email_id" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="spec" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="state" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="dob" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="gender" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="placeofpractice" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!--Changes end / -->
<field name="all" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="all"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr doesn't allow * in the fields search as a replacement for all fields.
There is [JIRA SOLR-4493](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4493) but no plans to fix it as well.
You would need to copy the fields you want to search on to a single field with the [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) directive and search on that field.

Also copyfield with source `*` is not yet supported.
[JIRA SOLR-4729](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4729) is not yet released, but you can try the patch.

You have to add individual fields or use a single field for all incoming fields.

Comment: I have added the copy field along with my original schema , i have edited the post with my schema.xml , can you check whether it's correct

Comment: and one more question , if i have to search for multiple words of the same field , is it necessary to include it in parantheses ?